# How can I programmatically click a child element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to click a button in Google Docs using a Chrome Extension content script.

In console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('docos-input-buttons')[0];
```

Yields:

```
<div class="docos-input-buttons"><div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action docos-input-post docos-input-buttons-post" style="user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Post Comment" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Post Comment">Comment</div><div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard docos-input-cancel" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Discard comment" aria-label="Discard comment" style="user-select: none;">Cancel</div></div>
```

Then I can dig down into the children:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('docos-input-buttons')[0].children[0];
```

Yields:

```
<div role="button" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action docos-input-post docos-input-buttons-post" style="user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Post Comment" tabindex="0" data-tooltip="Post Comment">Comment</div>
```

I would think adding .click() to the document.getElementsByClassName would then click this Element...but clearly I'm missing something.

When you manually click the button (it is styled as a button) a Google Docs comment is posted.

But the following yields "undefined".

```
document.getElementsByClassName('docos-input-buttons')[0].children[0].click();
```

How do you programmatically click a child node in plain javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all class's with getElementsByClassName and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784763/select-all-classs-with-getelementsbyclassname-and-click)

Comment: Well...yes...it's a div with a "role" of button. The UI is a button...

Can you 'trigger' a div click? Is that even a logical question? Thanks for looking!

Comment: It's correct that `click()` yields undefined. Also, you didn't define (or you didn't tell us) what should happen when that `div` is clicked, so what did you expect?

Comment: @dippas not a duplicate, that's a different issue…

Comment: @11teenth there's a way using `onclick`, but it ain't so pretty – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220486/click-on-a-div-with-regular-javascript

Comment: Thanks - will try. Also, I am using jQuery for everything...but content script seems to prefer plain Javascript. Since jQuery seems to allow 'click' event on a div, I'll try that...also the onclick method if that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by *But the following yields "undefined".*? Click event will not return any value.

Comment: In the console, after entering the specified line of Javascript, the result is 'undefined.'

Comment: `click()` method call returns `undefined` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click What value did expected to come?

Comment: I would expect the programmatic 'click' to be the equivalent of the user clicking on the button. Which I've successfully done for other buttons in Google Docs.

Comment: @11teenth Other buttons would be having click event handlers defined by google docs, it may not be the case for div elements.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you programmatically click a child node in plain javascript?

There are multiple problems with your code

- Based on the code you have shared, you don't have a class `docos-input-buttons`, try `docos-input-buttons-post` instead
- There is no `children` of the `div` you are trying to access. It only has text-node which can be accessed via `element.childNodes[0]` but it doesn't support `click` event.

Why not click the `div` itself

```
document.getElementsByClassName('docos-input-buttons-post')[0].click();
```

or

```
document.querySelector('docos-input-buttons-post').click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.

I did skip a step - I added the console results for calling the parent, which is the 'docos-input-buttons' class. The button/div I want to click is the [0] (first) child.

So just putting "document.getElementsByClassName('docos-input-buttons-post')[0].click();" into console doesn't yield anything...

I'm trying jQuery, which does fire but seems to be hitting the same limitations...the child element doesn't seem to be clickable...

Comment: @11teenth Can you please make a snippet or a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @11teenth Also, the click event will only yield anything if there is a click event handler on that element. If there is no click event handler assigned to the element, then it will not result in anything.

Comment: I don't think I can make a fiddle - this code is Google Docs and I'm interacting via a content script.

There is a click event handler because when you manually click the button/div it posts the comment...

Comment: @11teenth can you share the exact markup that you are dealing with?

Comment: @11teenth click event doesn't return anything https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click